# Disable listview row when checkbox is checked

Tags: android, checkbox, android-listview

In my application I am using Custom `Listview` with row as TextView and `CheckBox`.
Now I want that when I check `CheckBox` at that time that respective row have to Disable(unfocasable).
What should be the code inside **CheckBox OnCheckedChangeListener**

I also tried to disable rowlayout inside Listener but not got success...

following is code I am using inside getView method of Adapter

```
final RelativeLayout RL=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.VTRLmain);
        check.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) 
            {
                if (isChecked) 
                {   
                    RL.setEnabled(false);
                     templist.add(getItem(position));//using for another activity
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: put your all code mean holder here

Comment: simple if else can work out here. just do nothing if the check box is checked. but this will not disable row focusable

Comment: i am using another list for checked Items.. So doing nothing not feasible

Answer (score 2):

give in xml code for `checkbox`

```
android:focusable="false"
```

it won't hide listview textboxs.

and check the application `theme`.

Comment: xml code not matters here.  there should be code inside adapter class

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter there is a method named isEnabled which you can overide. Try to do in your custom adapter

Try this code:

```
@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
if(checkbox1.isChecked()){
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```